# Is there a way to evaluate string with liquid tags

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I need to provide page content reference list (it should contain references on sections on page).
The only way which I can see is to use `page.content` and parse it, but I stumbled on problem with data evaluation. For example I can pull out this string from `page.content`: `{{site.data.sdk.language}} SDK` but there is no way to make jekyll process it, it outputs as is.
Also I want to make it possible to create cross-pages links (on specific section on page, but that link generated by another inclusion and doesn't persist in `page.content` in HTML form).

Is there any way to make it evaluate values from `page.content`?

P.S. I'm including piece of code which should build page content and return HTML with list (so there is no recursions).
P.P.S. I can't use submodules, because I need to run this pages on github pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `{{ site.data.sdk.language | strip_html }}` do it? I don't know, most probably I didn't understand the problem. Can you elaborate more? Maybe provide a link to a post you're referring to?

Comment: Problem with custom liquid tags. For example `{% section title={{site.data,sdk.language}} %}` But inside of code which render this tag, "title" variable will be set to `{{site.data,sdk.language}}` not it's value stored in YAML data file. I found some workaround for that and iterate over `context.scopes` and search for useful variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the similar

```
{% assign title = site.data.sdk.language %}
```

which is a stock Liquid tag and does the job well, so instead of

```
{% section title={{site.data.sdk.language}} %}
```

write your code as

```
{% section title = site.data.sdk.language %}
```

The key here is that once you enter `{%`, you're in Liquid. Don't expect Liquid to go "Inception" all over itself. `{{` is just a shorthand for "print this to output", but an parameter passing is not output, it's just reading a variable.

You should be able to also go wild and do:

```
{% section title = site.data.sdk.language | capitalize %}
```

For more re-read the docs: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers

Comment: One caveat to the "Liquid doesn't go Inception" is the `include` tag, [which does](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes).

Comment: Good point! Just adds one more to the inconsistencies of this "language". Note that you can only use the `{{var}}` evaluation in place of the file name in `include`, all other arguments must have a single literal or single variable access expression meaning you can't use any filters there... :(