# Jekyll - Evaluate a string before assignment

Tags: jekyll, eval, liquid

I need to capture a string into a variable `tag`, then use this variable in [`site.tags.tag`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/). The code is:

```
{% capture tag %}programming{% endcapture %}
{{ tag }}
{%- assign titles = site.tags.tag | map: "title" -%}
{{ titles }}
```

This code only prints prints:

```
programming
```

But if I replace `site.tags.tag` with either `site.tags.programming` or `site.tags.'programming'` I get the desired output:

```
programming
title1 title2
```

Is there a way to evaluate the variable `tag` before the assignment? After reading a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914071/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-string-with-liquid-tags) I tried `site.tags.{{tag}}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`site.tags[tag]` might be what you're looking for.